# Conflicting Types error in C with some file io

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

So here is my code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    double mass1, mass2, tof, pixcm;
    char pofVfilename[50];
    double pix[50];
    double pofV[50];
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("usage: %s filename", argv[0]); 
   }
else
    {
        FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if(file == 0){
            printf("could not open file\n");
        }
        else{
            fscanf(file, "%lf %lf", &mass1, &mass2);
            fscanf(file, "%lf", &tof);
            fscanf(file, "%s", pofVfilename);
            fscanf(file, "%lf", &pixcm);
            fclose(file);
            printf("%lf%lf%lf%lf", mass1, mass2, tof, pixcm);  
            readinputpofV(pix, pofV, pofVfilename);
            printf("%f %f", pix[10], pofV[10]);
        }
            
    }
    return 0;
}


void readinputpofV(double pix[], double pofV[], char filname[]){
    FILE *file = fopen(filname, "r");
    if(file == 0){
        printf("could not open pofV file\n");
    }
    else{
        int result = 2;
        int i = 0;
        while(result == 2){
            result = fscanf(file, "%lf %lf", &pix[i], &pofV[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

The error I get is

> warning: conflicting types for ‘readinputpofV’
>
> warning: previous implicit declaration of ‘readinputpofV’ was here

Can someone help.  Also, I am brand new to file input and was hoping for some guidance on how I am doing.

Answer (score 5):

This has **nothing** to do with the File I/O.

Try putting `void readinputpofV(double pix[], double pofV[], char filname[]);`
**above** `main()`.

The call to the function is being taken as it's declaration, and the return type is being assumed as `int`. Hence the confusion.

Comment: "This has **nothing** to do with file I/O" - exactly. Retagged.

Answer (score 1):

> previous **implicit** declaration of ‘readinputpofV’ was here

An *implicit* declaration makes the return type assumed to be `int` (in C89/C90, implicit declarations have been removed in C99). So the assumed type and the type of the definition are not compatible.

Therefore the compiler warns about the conflicting types.

It is just a warning, and not an error, though, and since the implemented type has `void` return type, you're not going to use the return value, so the code has a nonzero probability of working. But you should of course declare the function with the correct type before you are using it.

Comment: Thanks that was it I changed the readinputpofV to return int and now it works.

Comment: Better, declare it before using it.

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm not too well versed in prehistoric languages, but iirc, in C89, reaching the `}` terminating a function with non-void return type was only UB if you used the return value. If it was ignored, that was allowed. Could misremember, though.

Comment: @DanielFischer I doubt you don't remember well :) But I don't see why C is permissive here and not logically permissive elsewhere. For example, doing arithmetic on an invalid pointer counts as undefined as well, even if you don't dereference it. According to this logic, this should be undefined, even if you don't use the return value.

Comment: @H2CO3 I think that is explained by history. Originally, there was no `void`, so a "procedure" (as it was called in Pascal, cue not-really-fond faint memories) had to have a return type. But of course it was annoying to always have to write a `return 0;` or so at the end, compilers allowed omitting the `return` (with at least almost-officially guaranteed behaviour), people wrote code using that feature. So when the language was standardised, some of the dubious pratices were officially sanctioned in order to not invalidate too many implementations and too much legacy code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the `readinputpofV()` function before using it, else the compiler will assume it returns `int`, whereas it later encounters that it really returns `void`.

What you should do is adding

```
void readinputpofV(double pix[], double pofV[], char filname[]);
```

before the definition of `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the compiler couldn't readinputpofV while is compiling main function is assuming that this function is returning an int
If you move the definition of the function before the main. The warning will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Besides declaring the function prototype above main, you can write the whole definition of readinputpofV above main. Thus, you will avoid the error without needing to declare the function prototype.

---

I often use that tactic when I find it visually helpful, but it has it's downside: When you use multiple functions that interact with each other, that tactic may lead to compiler errors if you don't place the functions in the correct order. C programs are compiled serially; invoked functions should be known.

So, in C, to avoid implicit declaration compiler errors, any invoked function's definition or it's prototype, should be placed above any functions that might invoke it. You can just write them from bottom to top.